# Which syntax to choose for the semantics steps.fals as target and source module?

Tags: lightning-workbench, f-alloy

For the semantics section when initializing the steps.fals which part should be selected as source module and target module - the abstract or the concrete syntax?

Comment: Please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the semantics is defined in Lightning as an endogenous transformation from/to the Semantics Domain Model